# switch does nothing on Decompiled Android Source

Tags: android, for-loop, while-loop, apk, decompiler

```
switch(paramMotionEvent.getAction())
{
}
do
{
   for(;;)
   {
      return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(paramMotionEvent);
      this.prevX = MotionEvent.obtain(paramMotionEvent).getX();
   }
}while(Math.abs(paramMotionEvent.getX() - this.prevX) <=this.touchSlop);
return false;
}
}
```

Hi, I decompiled a few APK files. While analyzing those source code, I found weird lines similar to above code.

Why does the `switch` do nothing? In addition, I don't know why there is such use for those `do - for - while` statement. Please tell me something.

Comment: 1) Please write a complete sentence for clarity. 2) Why are you decompiling someone else's application?

Comment: @JaredBurrows 1) Sorry, this is my first question on stackoverflow. 2) Since I'm trying to study reversing - on college computer security club

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based only on the code posted, it's impossible to say. Most likely you're using a bad decompiler and it gave incorrect output. A lot of the older decompilers aren't very good. Have you tried Procyon or Krakatau?

Also, if possible, please post the apk you're trying to analyze.

Comment: I used JD-GUI before, but Procyon shows better decompiled code. Thank you!